# How to rsync a list of files from current directory to the home directory of a remote user?

Tags: rsync

I want to deploy a list of file from inside a file let's say `files.lst`:

```
+ .profile
+ .hg/hgrc
+ .mc/*
- /*

rsync -vvltr . --include-from 'files.lst' . destdir
```

Desired behaviour:

- copy recusively all the files and directories from `.mc`
- copy only `.hg/hgrc` file to destination, ignoring other files that could exist in that directory
- copy `.profile`

Comment: You mean `john@server:` right?  Otherwise, it would try to sync to a directory called 'john@server' and fail.

Comment: Could you define `doesn't work proper`? Wrong files? To many files? Wrong location?  Because the `--include-files file.LIST` // `--include FILE` is the way to go.

Comment: Did you really ask anyone in here to test before post? Is this a joke?!

Comment: @pfo it wasn't a joke, it's so easy to add a meaningless comments instead of verifying that what you think really works.

Comment: -1 for thinking this was an "Average User" site.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to make it working, definitely I would never recommend rsync to any *average* PC user (the one that never heard of `man` or `SF`).

```
+ .profile
+ .mc
+ .mc/***
+ .hg
+ .hg/hgrc
- /***
```

Explanations:

- you need to specify the directory first because otherwise it skip them
- the last line tells rsync to exclude everything that wasn't explicitly included.

Comment: You mean any average user who doesn't know how to RTFM.

Comment: Dude, you have an attitude problem which we call trolling, `man` was the first thing I opened and it does not include information about the patters and how they work. Instead I managed to find the solution on another question on SF, but after spending too much time for a simple problem like this.

Comment: I would recommend `rsync` to any Linux/UNIX system user for this purpose, it's a fantastic tool.  Like most fantastic tools, it requires some patience and learning.

Comment: What would you recommend? Windows Exploder?

Comment: I must agree with @SorinSbarnea: Only above-average people use `rsync`. ;-) .

Comment: That is odd the rsync man page on my system has a large section called `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`. That section it also happens to be in the web-based man page which you find if you search for `man rsync`.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I was agreeing with you that a lazy user is probably not a good candidate for this utility. I do not believe it is above anyone who is willing to read the manual to figure out the rest. Knowing the ins and outs of rsync should be in the toolbelt of almost anyone who considers themselves an IT professional or systems engineer. Now as for going back and down voting some of my previous answers... yeah that's not cool, but do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `--files-from` option.

`rsync --files-from=files.lst destination:/location/`

`man rsync`